# YUI equivalent to silmScroll, a minimal scrollbar

Tags: jquery, plugins, scrollbar, yui

I'm looking for a YUI3 equivalent to [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll), a jQuery plugin that shows a minimal scroll bar only when the content is hovered, scrolled using a mouse wheel or swiped on a tablet. The scrollbar overlays the content rather than having dedicated horizontal space.

The first example on the slimScroll site (linked above) shows the required functionality.

Comment: I do not see anything in the gallery (http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/), but slimScroll would not be hard to port. It's only a few hundred lines, and it looks like most of the jQuery functions used have counterparts in YUI's Node class.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I know of is ScrollView. http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/